# Flutter GetX state management with navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

#### Summary

I am currently building an app using **Flutter** with the help of the `get` package.

I cannot fully explain the current issue with only words, so I will make use of visual aids.

The below image shows the user flow of what's going on, with numbers indicating the order of the interaction/status.

[image: Current status]

#### Code

The below snippets are essential parts of what I think might be the key to a solution.

`post_page.dart`

```dart
class PostPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final pId = Get.parameters['post_id'];
  if(pId != null) {
    return GetX<PostController>(
      init: PostPageController(pId: pId),
      builder: (controller) => InformationAboutPostView(),
    );
  } else {
    return UnknownPostView();
  }
}
```

`post_page_controller.dart`

```dart
class PostPageController extends GetxController {
  final String pId;
  PostPageController({required this.pId});

  @override
  void onInit() {
    post.bindStream(PostRepo.stream(pId));
    super.onInit();
  }

  Rx<Post> post = Rx(Post.empty);
}
```

#### Things I know

1. The parameter is being delivered with no problemo.
2. The getxcontroller seems to stay in the memory, unless the page injected with it is being popped from the navigation stack.

#### Final questions from my investigations

- How to reuse the existing controller in the stack, but refreshing the stream value with a new one?
- Furthermore, how would one notify the change to the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner approach is to not reuse the controller, instead use tag property to create controller related to specific post.

to put controller releated to postA:

```
Get.put(PostPageController(), tag: postA.id);
```

and to find the controller

```
Get.find<PostPageController>(tag: postA.id);
```

if you are using GetView you can override tag getter

Comment: In my case, would it be implemented in a form of `Get.put(PostPageController(pId: pId), tag: pId)`?

Comment: @Johntopia yes.